# Can't load CSV to MySQL - (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

Tags: mysql, csv, docker

## Problem

I want to upload a .csv file to MySQL Docker.
Got the error : `File 'xx.csv' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)`

### My Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:latest
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD password

COPY ./sql-scripts/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY ./data /var/lib/mysql/
COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/

EXPOSE 3306
```

### My.cnf

```
[mysqld]
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql


secure-file-priv = ""
local-infile = 1 
symbolic-links=0
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

### I connect to MySQL as root:

```
docker exec -it mysql_1 mysql -uroot -proot_password
```

### Then execute SQL Command:

```
CREATE DATABASE data;
USE data;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pregnant_mapping` (
    `label` varchar(255),
    `Pregnancy` varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY
);
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql/pregnant_mapping.csv' INTO TABLE pregnant_mapping;
```

### What I've tried

Tried to add `LOCAL` in the command line, but doesn't work in my MySQL version; got the error: `ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below statement should work if you placed the .csv file in /var/lib/mysql directory

LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql/result' INTO TABLE mst_result FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Answer (score 0):

Seen this question a bit late, but maybe the answer may help somebody:

Platform: Linux (CENTOS 8)

1. In /etc/my.cnf.d/mysql-server.cnf, set

> ```
> [mysqld]
> local-infile = 1
> ```

2. Restart your MySQL-demon with

> service mysqld restart

3. Use mysqlimport and specify that local infiles are allowed:

> mysqlimport --user=${user} --password=${password} --local=TRUE -d
> ${database}  your_file

Add additional parameters to mysqlimport in case you need them.